# Dificuldade no select distinct sum

Tags: sql

O meu objetivo é mostrar 1 email com 1 total mas tou a ter dificuldade
Já tentei esse código:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, totalcopias FROM dados
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IkU71.png
```

E também tentei esse aqui:

```
SELECT DISTINCT email, totalcopias FROM dados GROUP BY email
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa31d.png
```

Mas não tou conseguindo juntar os totais.

Comment: queria que o 14166@espamol.pt mostrasse um valor como o gsdfgs@gfasgsa.pt sendo os únicos com valores

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode tentar fazer desta forma

```
SELECT email, MAX(totalcopias) as total FROM dados GROUP BY email
```

Esta query vai te mostrar o maior total de cada e-mail.

Caso a sua necessidade fosse somar todos os totais de cópia, você faria assim:

```
SELECT email, SUM(totalcopias) as total FROM dados GROUP BY email ORDER BY SUM(totalcopias)
```

Comment: era isso obrigado